# Translating route segments with ZF's gettext adapter

Tags: zend-framework, gettext, zend-route, zend-translate

I want to try out the route translations in Zend Framework, but I'm using the gettext adapter and the most tutorials have PHP translate adapter, so I'm having problems to make it work.

In the main Bootstrap.php I have the method in which I set the routes:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $front->getRouter();

$translator = Zend_Registry::get('Zend_Translate');
Zend_Controller_Router_Route::setDefaultTranslator($translator);

$routerRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('@about',
     array(
      'module'     => 'default',
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action'     => 'about'
    )
);
$router->addRoute('about', $routerRoute);
```

This works for `/about` path.
I'll paste the code in which I set Zend_Translate, but it basically loads a `*.mo` file depending on current session language:

```
$langParam = $this->getSessionLang();

$localeString = $languages[$langParam];
$locale       = new Zend_Locale($localeString);

$moFilePath = $langFolder . $langParam . '.mo';
if (!file_exists($moFilePath)) {
    throw new Zend_Exception('File does not exist: ' . $moFilePath);
}

$translate = new Zend_Translate(
        array(
            'adapter'        => 'gettext',
            'content'        => $moFilePath,
            'locale'         => $locale,
            'ignore'         => array('.'), // ignore SVN folders
            'disableNotices' => ('production' === APPLICATION_ENV) // disable notices in Production
            )
        );

Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Locale'   , $locale);
```

This, ofc, it's called `prior` to routing.

My question: can gettext be used as a translation adapter for a route, because I can't figure out how can I catch the `@about` string with, let's say, poEdit? It can? Hooray! How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, my mo's were all messed up. So there's no problem with the code.

Here's how you edit your mo files so that the route can translate it (I'm presume you have your ZF i18n working - Translate, Locale and the like):

**1. Remember this?**

```
$routerRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('@about',
     array(
      'module'     => 'default',
      'controller' => 'index',
      'action'     => 'about'
    )
);
```

**2. See that *'@about'* string?** That's the soon-to-be-translated path. So how do you translate a string so that poEdit will catch it? Well, you don't; not with poEdit anyway. You manually edit the `.po file`:

```
#ro.po
msgid  "about"
msgstr "despre"

#en.po
msgid  "about"
msgstr "about"
```

The msgid should match your path string (minus the '@' string, ofc).

**3. Now go open your po file with poEdit.** You'll see a new string (surprised, huh?). Compile this `po` to get a new shiny `mo` file that ZF can use.

**4. Now my `site.com/about` or `site.com/despre` paths work.**

[More info here.](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard.translated-segments)