# Translating URLs ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, routes, zend-translate

I have been using zend translate to translate the site content but what about the urls? How could I translate it?

Ex.:
localhost/app/contact  (English)
localhost/app/contato  (Portuguese)

Comment: How are you translating the site content?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525159/translating-route-segments-with-zfs-gettext-adapter/7537468#7537468) wil help.

Comment: @emaillenin I'm translating the static content with Zend Translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are indeed using Zend Translate you should be able to use translations in your router like:

```xml
routes.someroute.route = "/:langparam/@translateme"
routes.someroute.defaults.module = public
routes.someroute.defaults.controller = page
routes.someroute.defaults.action = show
```

If your translation source contains 'translateme' it wil be translated, if not the router will use 'translateme' as value.